# Hi, could someone please check what I am doing wrong in this fold left program?

Tags: scheme, racket

Define a SCHEME function, named (fold-left op initial sequence), which is another
accumulate procedure except that fold-left applies the operator to the first element of the
list first and then the next until it reaches the end of the list. That is, fold-left combines
elements of sequence working in the opposite direction from fold-right.

```
(define (fold-left op initial sequence) 
   (define (iter result rest) 
     (if (null? rest) 
         result 
         (iter (op result (car rest)) 
               (cdr rest)))) 
   (iter initial sequence))
```

Comment: Why do you think you're doing wrong? Code seems ok. Except it's not well formatted.

Comment: You're applying `op` to its arguments in the opposite order to the Racket `foldl`, so that might be the problem.

Comment: Note that you don't really need the `iter` local function: `(iter result rest)` is just `(fold-left op result rest)`.  I think writing it that way makes it clearer (for me anyway).

Comment: The problem statement - "another accumulate procedure" makes it seem like you've already written a `fold-right`. If so, `(fold-left op init seq)` can just be `(fold-right op init (reverse seq))`